# running x code inside of a docker container

Tags: reactjs, react-native, docker, kubernetes, skaffold

is it possible to run x code inside of a docker container. i am encountering several errors when running the command skaffold dev when trying to start my project.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json files
COPY package*.json ./

# Install project dependencies
RUN npm ci

# Copy the rest of the project files
COPY . .

# Set the environment variable to non-interactive
ENV CI=1

# Expose the necessary port for the Expo development server
EXPOSE 19000

# Install the required package globally (optional)
RUN npm install -g @expo/ngrok@^4.1.0

# Start the Expo development server
CMD ["npx", "expo", "start", "--ios", "--non-interactive"]
```

and these are the errors i am getting:
Xcode must be fully installed before you can continue. Continue to the App Store?
For this particular error, i already have x code installed on my computer. is this stating that i need to have x code installed inside of a docker container?